# ¿Porqué el metodo invocado no modifica los valores del array? Java

Tags: java

estoy provando a modificar los valores de un array desde un método, el problema que me encuentro es que el argumento no se modifica. Me devuelve los mismos valores que hay antes del pasar por el metodo. ¿Porqué no los modifica?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Prueba{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double [] notasTrimestre = {2, 4, 8};
        modificar(notasTrimestre);
        System.out.println(notasTrimestre[0] + " " + notasTrimestre[1] + " " + 
        notasTrimestre[2]);

    }

    public static void modificar(double notas []){
        notas = new double[3];
        notas[0] = 7;
        notas[1] = 8;
        notas[2] = 10;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Porque en `modificar()` creas una nueva referencia al objeto en esta línea:

```
notas = new double[3];
```

De modo que el `notas` que modificas ahí es el de esa nueva referencia, no el que recibes en parámetro.

Así debería funcionar:

```
public static void modificar(double notas []){
    notas[0] = 7;
    notas[1] = 8;
    notas[2] = 10;
}
```

Si haces una prueba como esta:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double [] notasTrimestre = {2, 4, 8};
    System.out.printf("%-45s%s%n","Referencia original en método main:",notasTrimestre);
    modificar(notasTrimestre);
    System.out.println(notasTrimestre[0] + " " + notasTrimestre[1] + " " + 
    notasTrimestre[2]);
}

public static void modificar(double notas []){
    System.out.printf("%-45s%s%n","Referencia original en método modificar:",notas);
    notas = new double[3];
    System.out.printf("%s%n%-45s%s%n","Referencia nueva en método modificar","...Después de la asignación:",notas);
    notas[0] = 7;
    notas[1] = 8;
    notas[2] = 10;
}
```

Verás algo más o menos así en pantalla:

```
Referencia original en método main:          [D@85ede7b
Referencia original en método modificar:     [D@85ede7b
Referencia nueva en método modificar
...Después de la asignación:                 [D@5674cd4d
2.0 4.0 8.0
```

En `modificar()`, la referencia seguía siendo la misma que en `main()` hasta antes de la asignación: `[D@85ede7b`, pero luego de la asignación: `notas = new double[3];` ya `notas` pasó a tener otra referencia: `[D@5674cd4d` y era esa referencia la que se estaba modificando, no la original.

Comment: Muchas gracias, entendido, estoy creando otro array a una referencia diferente.